# $m<n$ is which rank of numbers who has scratched?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I find prime numbers with Sieve of Eratosthenes for numbers from 1 to $n$. How many numbers has scratched before $m$. For $1\leq m\leq n$?

Comment: Are you trying to find the prime $m$ that eliminates a given non-prime $n$?  Or to find how many numbers are eliminated by a given $n$?  Or something else?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have edited question. please have an other look.

Comment: I'm not sure that helped much to clarify what you are asking.  Is there anything special about $n$? what about $m$?  How far through the sieving algorithm are you before stopping and asking the question (having stopped after the $m$th iteration or have you completed all $n$ iterations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $n$ is very large, so we can ignore "end effects".  As an example, if $n$ is even, $2$ will eliminate $\frac {n-2}2$ numbers, while if $n$ is odd $2$ will eliminate $\frac {n-1}2$ numbers. For many purposes we can ignore the constant and say $2$ eliminates half the numbers and so on.  In that case, each prime $p_i$ will eliminate $1-\frac 1{p_i}=\frac {p_i-1}{p_i}$ of the numbers. The fraction remaining after the primes below $m$ are then $$\prod_{p_i \lt m} 1-\frac 1{p_i}$$ and the number remaining is just $n$ times this.  Is this accurate enough, or do you want to keep track of the constants?